# Reloading a CAPTCHA in php-login MVC

Tags: php, html

I'm following the php-login MVC (https://github.com/panique/php-login) to understand the MVC architecture.

In Register page, we have a CAPTCHA generated in img tag. I'm trying to add a Reload Captcha option to refresh the CAPTCHA by the user. I've tried reading the $_SESSION variable for the captcha, but it always returns the previously loaded captcha value.

I've tried hard to do this, but all went in failure. So I need your help in trying to understand this part.

Note: In the demo Register page of the php-login mvc (http://demo-professional.php-login.net/login/register), the author has given a small note below the CAPTCHA text box

> Please note: This captcha will be generated when the img tag requests the captcha-generation (and a real image) from YOURURL/login/showcaptcha. As this is a client-side triggered request, the $_SESSION["captcha"] dump in the footer will not show the captcha characters. The captcha generation happens AFTER the rendering of the footer.

I got what the Author is trying to say, but still I'm unable to fix it.

Comment: Did you install all the Dependencies using composer.json?

Comment: I've installed only the below dependencies:

phpmailer/phpmailer, gregwar/captcha. 
Am I missing anything?

Comment: try to install all the deps once,it may works.i installed all of em and it works fine.

Answer (score -3):

1. Install composer
2. Open the 'php-login' folder
3. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> and right-click. Select the "Open command window here" option.
4. Type 'composer' into the console to verify that everything's OK.
5. If so, type 'composer update', and it will update with the vendor folder.

I hope this helps!